# Confusion with PHP - working out percentages of numbers

Tags: php, math

Here's what I'm trying to do: the user enters a number ($number) and chooses a percentage level ($percent). I want to find out the percentage of the number, then take it away from the original number.

Example: I have 100p, and I want to calculate 25% off of it. So the answer is 25p, so 100p - 25p = 75p. The final answer is 75p.

However for some strange reason when I run the code below it returns either 98 or 99 for all cases.

```
        $percent = $_POST['percent']; // The level I want to take off the product
        $number = $_POST['number']; // The initial value of the product

        $answer = ($number / 100) * $percent;

        $finalanswer = $number - $answer;

        echo "The answer is $finalanswer";
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this. Please note that this is simplifying it a LOT. It just helps you see how the calculation works. :)

```
$percent = $_POST['percent'];
$number = $_POST['number'];

$percent_in_decimals = $percent/100;

$temp = $number*$percent_in_decimals;

$final_answer = $number - $temp;

echo "The final answer is {$final_answer}!";
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I take it this works on your machine? When I run it, I still get 99 for some weird reason..

Comment: @JoshuaDempsey Are you sure your `$_POST` values are correct then? Try echoing them out before the actual calculation and see what you get.

Comment: Silly me, I forgot to retrieve the actual content of my <select> tag that fed the percentages in.. hence it was always dragging in 1. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2):

your input is string, you have to convert it to e.g. float like this:

```
$percent = floatval($_POST['percent']);
$number = floatval($_POST['number']);
```

now use @9997 code...

```
$percent_in_decimals = $percent/100;

$temp = $number*$percent_in_decimals;

$final_answer = $number - $temp;

echo "The final answer is {$final_answer}!";
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `$answer` algorithm is incorrect. Change it to this.

```
$answer = $number * ($percent/100);
```

Here's a fiddle, just showing how it works.. *obviously not in php* for the demo http://jsfiddle.net/wm9U2/